# How to create JNLP file for a java web application?

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a java program that I ultimately want to deploy it on the web.

I started off creating a jar file from bunch of classes:

> jar cfe tbi.jar trail1modified
>   trail1modified.class
>   InitialKeypad.class
>   InitialKeypad$1.class
>   InitialKeypad$2.class
>   InitialKeypad$thehandler.class
>   InitialKeypad$thehandler2.class
>   InitialKeypad$thehandler3.class
>   InitialKeypad$thehandler4.class
>   Keypad5$1.class
>   Keypad5$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad5$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad5$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad5.class Keypad6$1.class
>   Keypad6$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad6$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad6$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad6.class Keypad7$1.class
>   Keypad7$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad7$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad7$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad7.class  Keypad8$1.class
>   Keypad8$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad8$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad8$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad8.class  Keypad9$1.class
>   Keypad9$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad9$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad9$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad9.class  Keypad10$1.class
>   Keypad10$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad10$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad10$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad10.class  Keypad11$1.class
>   Keypad11$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad11$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad11$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad11.class  Keypad12$1.class
>   Keypad12$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad12$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad12$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad12.class  Keypad13$1.class
>   Keypad13$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad13$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad13$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad13$thehandler4.class 
>   Keypad13.class  Keypad14$1.class
>   Keypad14$thehandler.class 
>   Keypad14$thehandler2.class
>   Keypad14$thehandler3.class
>   Keypad14$thehandler4.class
>   Keypad14.class  ReKeypad.class
>   ReKeypad$1.class ReKeypad$2.class
>   ReKeypad$thehandler.class
>   ReKeypad$thehandler2.class
>   ReKeypad$thehandler3.class
>   ReKeypad$thehandler4.class time.class
>   time2.class trail2$1.class
>   trail2$2.class trail2.class UO$1.class
>   UO$2.class UO$thehandler.class
>   UO$thehandler2.class
>   UO$thehandler3.class UO.class

Now I wish to create a JNLP file. I am following this http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html

I am bit lost on the JNLP part. How do I create it? And what does it signifies? Are there any tutoring videos on (for example) creating a simple Hello World program --> jar file --> JNLP file --> HTML stage --> java web application.

Comment: Note that a WebStart Application and a Web Application are two very different application types.  A WebStart app is launched from the web, but then runs on the user's machine.  A Web app runs in a Servlet container on a web server.

Comment: Oh ok. Webstart application is the one I am interested in

Answer (score 5):

A brief Description:

`Java Web Start is a mechanism for program delivery through a standard Web server. Typically initiated through the browser, these programs are deployed to the client and executed outside the scope of the browser. Once deployed, the programs do not need to be downloaded again, and they can automatically download updates on startup without requiring the user to go through the whole installation process again`

Look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/). This includes the simplest and comapct steps to create a jnlp file.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html), still from Oracle, but definitely better!

Specific topic about JNLP syntax: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#example

Answer (score 1):

And take a minute, pack your classes into jar. It is much more convenient!

Comment: Yeah a .jar file will make your life easier